# JMeter JMS point to point sampler not taking parameters

Tags: jmeter, jms

I am trying to setup a JMS point to point sampler in JMeter.
A CSV file is used to provide the JMS queue names as parameter.
However the connection fails to pick up the queue supplied by the CSV.
Tested this the same way on publisher and it works just fine.
Anyone has encountered this before?

[The setup of sampler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG83w.jpg)

[The result says cannot find queue with name '${que}', it is not treating this as a parameter?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGljt.jpg)

[However in the request part, it can use the correct value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtQq7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in JMeter, I would recommend reporting it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime you can work it around by converting a [JMeter Variable into a JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) **before** the JMS Point-to-Point sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   props.put('que', vars.get('que'))
   ```
3. Replace `${que}` with [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) call

   ```
   ${__P(que,)}
   ```

   [image: JMeter JMS Point to Point queue name]
4. That's it, now you should be able to parameterize your topic name

   [image: JMeter parameterize jms topic name]

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try it out in a moment.
I decompiled the jms.jar and found the clear class is taking (queue) as the input parameter while the publisher is taking (string) as the name input.
so i guess these two sampler works completely differently although they are both under JMS sampler.