# Jmeter Dynamic JMS queue name values are not updated from CSV Data Config

Tags: jmeter, jms, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to perform a performance test using Jmeter JMS, I have a csv file feeding testdata in the form
APPLICATIONAME,SEND_QUEUE,RECV_QUEUE,MSG_TO_SEND
I have some 300-400 odd msgs and my test plan looks as follows

[image]
[image]

I have tried setting property variables **tqueue_get, tqueue_put** following a suggestion from the below post [JMeter JMS point to point sampler not taking parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832872/jmeter-jms-point-to-point-sampler-not-taking-parameters?rq=1)

[image]
[image]

The weird thing is that when I check the log, I can see the variables tqueue_get and tqueue_put set correctly in the debug sampler but the JMS test sampler either takes the wrong queue name (as if reading the prev row or something) or simply takes no name at all like below

[image]

Can someone point in me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:

> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code **as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

so replace your [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) call with something like:

```
props.put('tqueue_put', vars.get('mq_queue_put'))
props.put('tqueue_put', vars.get('mq_queue_get'))
```

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on these `props`, `vars` and other shorthands

Also be aware that properties are **global** so in case of concurrency 2 threads will be writing to the same queue so you might want to add i.e. [current thread number](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as the property prefix or postfix